# Which characters can enter the mirror realm on their own?

Tags: dc

In the DC universe which characters can enter the mirror world/realm of the Mirror master on their own? Other than the Mirror master which other superheroes or villains can enter his world using their powers? Mirror master can make others travel to his world with him but I want to know that which other characters can travel to mirror world using their powers?

Comment: Based on [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/260127/who-is-this-character-in-injustice-and-how-is-she-able-to-do-this) question I know that Raven can enter the mirror realm which other characters can do this.

Comment: https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Mirror_World / https://comicvine.gamespot.com/mirror-world/4020-56078/- Surprisingly few...

Comment: Probably all of his alternates can access their local variant; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_Master#Other_versions

Comment: @Valorum Your second link in your first comment results in a 404 page.

Comment: https://comicvine.gamespot.com/mirror-world/4020-56078/